# Os processos executados em paralelo tem relação com o numero de núcleos das CPUs?

Tags: python, paralelismo, cpu

Estou estudando o módulo [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) do Python, no qual me permitir rodar vários processos em paralelo (no meu entendimento). Como um caso de ilustração vamos ver o exemplo abaixo:

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process


def create_process(func):    
    return Process(target=func)
    

def run_process(process_list):
    for process in process_list:
        process.start()

    for process in process_list:
        process.join()


def task1():
    for i in range(5):
        print('Task 1', i + 1)
        time.sleep(1)


def task2():
    for i in range(5):
        print('Task 2', i + 1)
        time.sleep(1)


run_process([create_process(task1), create_process(task2)])
```

No qual gera a seguinte saída:

> Task 2 1
> Task 1 1
> Task 2 2
> Task 1 2
> Task 1 3
> Task 2 3
> Task 1 4
> Task 2 4
> Task 1 5
> Task 2 5

Perceba que para o nosso exemplo de ilustração eu criei 2 processos, e é neste ponto que começa a surgir minhas dúvidas que estão ligadas com a quantidade de núcleos do processador e a capacidade de executar a tarefa em paralelo.

## Dúvidas

- Cada processo é executado em um núcleo da CPU de maneira
  independente/paralelo?
- Quando eu for criar vários processos em paralelo eu devo considerar o
  número de núcleos da CPU? Exemplo: uma CPU de 8
  núcleos devo criar apenas oito processos?